# Is deep linking redirect work with click/touch event generated by jquery trigger method?

Tags: javascript, deeplink

Actually, I am trying to deep link from my web url to app. I have used the code from https://github.com/hampusohlsson/browser-deeplink and everything is working till checking the app installed or not. Now, the problem is that I am executing the deeplink.open() method of the said code and then as per return true/false I am trying to redirect the user to my deeplink app url. Note: I am not executing the .open() method on click event. As my page dont trigger any click event with physical touch on the screen, the code for redirecting window.location = "native/url" is not working. If i execute the code window.location = "native/url" on any button click it is working. Event I tried to generate the click event with trigger method still the window.location to redirect to native is not working. Can any please tell me whether we need to a physical touch on the screen or can we do the same with jquery trigger method?

```
function redirectUrl(OS, webUrl, appUrl){
            if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)){
                deeplink.setup({
                    iOS: {
                        appId: "ISOAPP",
                        appName: "facebook",
                    },
                    android: {
                        appId: "com.myandroid.app.dev"
                    }, 
                    url: {
                        mobileUrl: appUrl,
                        webUrl: webUrl
                    }
                });                    
                var result = deeplink.open(appUrl)
                if(result == true){ 
                    //app is installed
                    $("#redirectButton").on("click", function() {                            
                        window.location = "mynative://home";
                    });
                    $("#redirectButton").trigger("click");                        
                }else {
                    window.location = webUrl;
                }
            }else{
                //for desktop web
                window.location = webUrl;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hi Guys, I veriried the code in mob-firefox browser and its working as expected. The issue with chrome android.

Comment: Hi All, I just got the reason of the code not working in chrome. I found the below information from https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents 

Chrome doesn’t launch an external app for a given Intent URI in the following cases.
1. When the Intent URI is redirected from a typed in URL.
2. When the Intent URI is initiated without user gesture.